# Adding items on ListView (simple?)

Tags: android, listview

Is there a way to add items on listview without adding a class or doing something really complicated? I searched everywhere but they seem so complicated. So help me please!

Answer (score 0):

ListView is designed as AdapterView to reduce memory usage and to make it faster. You cannot add views to a ListView directly, you have to use you own Adapter.

You can you use **ScrollView** to add a few views and scroll it like ListView does.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as complicated as you think. You need:

- a list of *things*
- a View to display one *thing*
- an Adapter to populate the View with the corresponding *thing*

Lots of tutorial on the web, [one for example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)